Does Artifact negate Blasphemy's "Die next turn" effect?
The description for the Artifact effect is

Negates the next debuff

The description for the Blasphemy card is

Enter Divinity. Die next turn.

Does the Artifact effect negate Blasphemy's "Die next turn" effect?

According to the Slay the Spire Wikia Blasphemy is a buff and therefore does not get blocked by Artifact.

Blasphemy's effect is considered a buff, preventing Artifact from blocking it.

You may survive the effect of Blasphemy with a stack of Intangible though.

A Buffer will also save you. (Fossilized Helix or Prismatic Shard may make it available.)
